# como mostrar pagina web local?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

como puedo mostrar una pagina web local?
yo ya hice algo parecido pero mostrando una url, no una pagina web local
(de esta manera mostre la pagina url

```
m_messageWidget->messageView->setHomepageUrl(QUrl(QString::fromUtf8("urlutilizada").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationVersion())));
```

necesito poder reemplazar eso por una pagina web local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas facilitarle la URL al widget `QWebView`. Este widget está diseñado para visualizar contenido HTML:

```
QUrl url(QString::fromUtf8("urlutilizada").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationVersion());

QWebView *view = new QWebView(parent);
view->load(url);
view->show();
```

Comment: pero puedo hacerlo con una direccion local?
por ejemplo con un "file://usr/doc/algo"?

Comment: @AdolfoComas entiendo que debería funcionar

Comment: vale muchas gracias, voy a probar :)